# Reshaping automatic polygon edge based on reference layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, geoprocessing, feature-class

i have two polygon layer, one for Region administrative"Reference layer", and the second is administrative border is governorates.

Governorates border is not identical with Region border. So there is any idea to perform reshape automatic Governorates border with Region border

[some_text http://www91.zippyshare.com/scaled/yuf4eBnj/file.html](http://www91.zippyshare.com/scaled/yuf4eBnj/file.html)

Comment: It won't qualify as automatic but I think you need to Start Editing, select a polygon and use Reshape Feature with the Trace tool.

Comment: You can try using the Stap Geoprocessing tool if you have a Standard or Advanced license.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000  and  http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0412/use-the-snap-geoprocessing-tool-to-automate-editing.html

Comment: The align to shape tool  might work for you: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Aligning_features_to_a_shape/01m800000004000000/

Answer (score 1):

INPUTS:

[image]

ASSUMPTION:

Region belongs to governorate, if majority of region's area belongs to that governorate.

SOLUTION:

Intersect  regions and governorates. Remove all the fields, but governorate and region ids. Calculate area and sort table in descending order by area:

[image]

Select non-first records in above table using region id and delete these records.

Join intersect table to regions, using region id field:

[image]

And dissolve it using governorate id.

RESULT:

[image]

Note some minor editing might be possible for small regions if you don't like the governorate they will end up within

Comment: Thank you very much@FelixIP, i followed your explain, but unfortunately "Dissolve" did not succeed with me. the result of Dissolve eat all "Governorates" border and keep "Region" geometry only.

Comment: If your regions have slivers between them, solution will not work.

Comment: No, governorates it's a subdivision of borders, Unlike the borders of regions, so regions is "Face 1" governorates is "Face 2", see this image green outline is "region" black outline is "governorates" 
http://rghost.net/65rQCGkjK/image.png

Comment: My understanding that you want boundary of something big and inaccurate to match boundaries of small higher resolution bits inside. Make a copy of smalls, start editing. Merge ones you think make a boundary of their bigger container. If you succeed and this is what you want, proceed with my solution because it is automated process. If this is not what you want or merging will fail to represent a boundary of biggie, disregard my solution

Comment: Just swap what i called regions with other thing

Comment: OK, anyway thank you very much, i think merge will fail, because the boundary between two layers have many overlaps and shifts.

Comment: Is it possible to get an update on this? I’m having trouble understanding the explanation provided by FelixIP

Comment: @C Smith The only unusual thing is selection of non-first records, see if this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154 will help.