# Auto incrementing field based on groups within feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am needing to auto increment a field based on groups within a feature class. I have 8 plots within a given polygon and I need to assign them an ID from 1-8 for each set of plots within each polygon. The polygon would have its own unique ID number to be used to group the plots.

I assume it would be an alteration of this:

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Field calculator for Python

```
d={}
def GroupOrder(groupID):
  if groupID in d: d[groupID]+=1
  else: d[groupID]=1
  return d[groupID]
```

## ---------------------------

```
GroupOrder( !locality! )
```

Change !locality! to relevant field.

UPDATE:
This variation of expression:

```
d={}
def GroupOrder(groupID):
  N=d.get(groupID,0);N+=1
  d[groupID]=N
  return N
```

Should work much faster on large datasets.

Comment: If the GroupOrder function were to be used in a stand-alone python script, the `GroupOrder` function would be the `code block` argument and the `GroupOrder( !locality! )` would be the 'expression' argument.

Comment: In script it is: a) create dictionary b) update cursor on 2 fields group and one to be populated. 3-5 lines of code.

Comment: I neglected to mention in my comment that those arguments would be included in the arcpy calculate field tool: `arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)` if used in a stand-alone script. Thanks for describing the steps of a different approach to using your code in a stand-alone script.

Comment: All good. Anyway I am under impression that da cursor is much faster than field calculator.

Comment: I want to do the same but group by ID column in shapefile and it is not working. I have replaced groupID by ID - d={}def GroupOrder( !ID! ):  N=d.get( !ID! ,0);N+=1  d[ !ID! ]=N  return N

Comment: Wrong way.  Change !locality!  to    !Id!