# Stratified sampling from point data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, sampling, twitter

I have 8000 points with a zipcode number.

Actually those are tweet points talking about zipcode, so multiple points have same number (e.g. 300 points with zipcode 32,805).

I want to get 800 sample points (as rule of having sampled mostly 10% of data) with stratified sampling where samples are drawn according to total number of points having same zipcode. e.g. 50 sample points from 300 points having 32,805 zipcode, maybe 10 from 100 points having zipcode 10,000 and so on.

I tried to find out sample questions to solve my problem but failed.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3?

Comment: Perhaps try to calculate sequential id based on a code. Take first 10 if total is 100. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154

Comment: You may get a quicker answer on the http://stats.stackexchange.com/ website?

Comment: I am voting to leave it open (against closing as off-topic --> no clear GIS component), because sampling points/lines/polygons (and the techniques of sampling) using GIS software is a routinely processing task a GIS analyst may have.

Answer (score 1):

This would give you another option:
[Sampling Design Tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ecbe1fc44f35465f9dea42ef9b63e785):

> The Sampling Design Tool for ArcGIS 10 provides a means to effectively
>   develop sampling strategies.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try the [Areal Sampling Toolbox](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1fec0fd6cd0641a6bab913a89e76fb6b) which is (with my bolding):

> A toolbox for generating sample points using random sampling,
>   **stratified sampling**, systematic sampling, cluster sampling, and
>   aligned sampling.