# Select By attribute - top 100 values for each district

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, syntax, split-by-attribute

I am trying to determine the highest 100 values for each district in a shapefile. I have 27 unique districts and 62834 records, but not sure how to proceed. I could "split by attribute" based on the district and select the highest 100 but I would have to repeat this like 30 times for each district.... Is there any easier way or syntax I could use? The value column is number of males in each Small Area Layer in Each district. Using ArcMap 10.3...

Comment: Sort 62k records in descending order and populate new field using https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have been out the office for the past week.. Will try out your solution and get back to you ASAP. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a script using the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm) of ArcGIS. Add your shapefile to the map and execute the code. Top values per region will be selected.

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict

fc = 'Layer_name' #Change to match layer name in table of contents
fields = ['OID@','District','Value_field'] #Change name of District and Value_field to match the field names of your data
number_of_top_values = 100 #Number of top values per district to select

#List all features and sort by district and value field
all_features = sorted([list(i) for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields)], reverse=True, key = lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))

#Create a dictionary of top values. Regions as keys and Object IDs as values
d = defaultdict(list)
for oid, region, value in all_features:
    if len(d[region]) < number_of_top_values:
        d[region].append(oid)

#Select by object ids
oids_to_select = tuple([item for sublist in list(d.values()) for item in sublist])
sql_clause = '{0} IN {1}'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName), str(oids_to_select))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=fc, where_clause=sql_clause)
```

Screenshot from ArcGIS Pro but it is the same in ArcGIS Desktop. I have 16 districts in my data:

[image]