# Select specific polygon intersecting another polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select

I have lots of building polygons in my parcels. Each with individual attributes. I want to select for each parcel the building polygon with the highest value from one field. How can I accomplish this in ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Sort by that column and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this is doing, but it is not working. For better understanding: I have layer 1 with my parcels and layer 2 with my buildings.  For each parcel in layer 1 I want to select the building from layer 2 with the max value of field z of all the polygons in that specific parcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified solution, because you did not understand one in comments.

INPUTS:
[image]
[image]

Sort houses using "VALUE" in descending order and delete identical using PARC_ID".

OUTPUT:
[image]