# Repeated labeling of random points within polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have created 3 random points within each of 27k polygons. I now want to label each of those 3 points as "A", "B", "C" within each polygon.

Is there a quick/automated way to do this?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154

Comment: Do you have a character (text) field to store the character in prior to labelling? Do you want there to be one instance of each of A, B and C for each polygon? Is there a field identifying the polygon each point resides in? Do you have any python ability?

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thanks for your help.  Yes, I can create a attribute in which to store the label character (A,B,C).  Yes I want an "A", "B", and "C" for points within each polygon (e.g. 27k polygons so 27k "A", 27k "B", 27k "C").  Each polygon has a unique ID.  I do have python.

Comment: A, B, C, could also be 1, 2, 3

Comment: First Spatial Join (or Intersect) the points to the polygons to get the FID or OBJECTID of the polygon into the points' attributes then refer to the answer by @FelixIP linked in his comment to field calculate the A, B and C for each unique polygon ID for every point using a dictionary to keep track. Have a stab at that and see how you go; if it doesn't work update your question with your code and any error messages you get.

Answer (score 2):

I created 3 random points in each polygon and called expression referred above to populate new text field:

```
chr(GroupOrder( !CID! )+64)
```

Output:

[image]