# Auto Incrementing Field based on Selection of Records in Feature Class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm attempting to write a script that will add an incremented value to a field based on a selection of records.

For example, the script will select the first 300 records in a feature class and then using calculate field assign a value of 1 to a field called "Week_Assignment". It will then select the next 300 records and assign a value of 2 to the same field, etc.

I'm able to select the records, but not able to calculate the field with an incremented value. I found some generic code on an Esri help forum that will auto increment every row in a field, but I need to modify it to add the same value to all rows in a selection.

Here's the sample code:

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 return rec

autoIncrement()
```

Comment: Select and calculate would require arcpy (or manual Calculate Field with the selection), and probably not very efficient. The autoIncrement function could be changed to include a different value based on the `rec` counter. Will you always be using 300 rows for each week?

Comment: I'm attempting to create a tool that will allow for inputs from the user, like the 
input feature class and number of analysts who will analyze the feature class. The number of rows selected will change based on the number of records in the feature class and the number of analysts.

Comment: Unless your set has records removed simple objectid // 300 will do.

Comment: Perhaps this answer could assist as well? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class

Comment: I did try using the suggested code in this thread and it just incremented over all of the rows in each selection. Selection 1 (rows 1 to 300) were assigned a value 1 to 300 in the "Week_Assignment" field, etc.. I suspect that this happened because I was using an integer in the autoIncrement expression rather than an ID field like in the example. Also, I'm using a variable to determine the number of rows that should be selected and I'm unclear about how to use the variable in the autoIncrement expression. I receive an error every time I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the sample code provided to account for a user-specified group interval. This uses division to identify the group number. I add pStart to account for the groups starting with 1.

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(groupinterval): 
 global rec
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  pGroup = pStart
  rec = pStart 
 else:
  pGroup = int(rec/groupinterval) + pStart #check with your version of Python; should be floor operation for integer division. 
  rec += pInterval  
 return pGroup

autoIncrement(300)
```

Since autoincrement(300) is a string parameter for the CalculateField geoprocessing tool, you could modify to use a variable in place here and then build the string, e.g.

```
usrval = 300 
increxp = "autoincrement({})".format(usrval)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(week_lyr, "Week_Assignment", increxp, "PYTHON", "rec=0 \\ndef autoIncrement(groupinterval): \\n global rec\\n pStart = 1 \\n pInterval = 1 \\n if (rec == 0): \\n pGroup = pStart\\n rec = pStart \\n else:\\n pGroup = int(rec/groupinterval) + pStart \\n rec += pInterval \\n return pGroup")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this modified code. I tried using it in my script within the calculate field function and it is assigning everything a value of 1. I should note that I am creating the row selections within a loop and then using the calculate field function to update the "Week_Assignment" field within the selection. Not sure if that is contributing to the issue.

Comment: The code from this answer uses the entire table, not a selection within the table. The groupinterval value controls how many rows are included for each "pGroup" value, so if you were to copy this code directly with a set of 300 rows you're only going to get 1 for every row; you'd get 1's and 2s if you have slightly more than 300; My recommendation would be to not use it with a selection.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The number of records that will need to be calculated will change based on an input from the user. I tried using an inline variable in the autoIncrement expression (autoIncrement(%tiles_wk%)), but I'm receiving a syntax error. Do you know if it's possible to use a variable as part of the expression input?

Comment: Please clarify, because my code above already uses the variable "groupinterval".

Comment: It may be more helpful to show you how I'm using your modified code within my script: arcpy.CalculateField_management(week_lyr, "Week_Assignment", "autoIncrement(300)", "PYTHON", "rec=0 \\ndef autoIncrement(groupinterval): \\n global rec\\n pStart = 1  \\n pInterval = 1 \\n if (rec == 0):  \\n  pGroup = pStart\\n  rec = pStart \\n else:\\n  pGroup = int(rec/groupinterval) + pStart  \\n  rec += pInterval  \\n return pGroup")

Comment: Since autoincrement(300) is a string parameter, you could modify to use a variable in place here and then build the string, e.g. `usrval = 300` and `increxp = "autoincrement({})".format(usrval)`

Comment: Yes! This is the piece that I was missing. Thanks for all of your help, this works perfectly.

Comment: Great! If it fixed your issue, kindly mark as accepted when you have a chance.