# Adding an incrementor in CalculateField_managment() expression

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-2.7, expression, autoincrement

I am trying to recalculate a value for a field using `arcpy.CalculateField_management()` using a tricky expression. Currently, I am recalculating one field named `REACH_ID`, using another field ('CO_FIPS') and them adding "01" + `'!REACH_ID[-5:]'`

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(layer_output,'REACH_ID','!CO_FIPS! + "01" + !REACH_ID![-5:]','PYTHON')
```

So if I had a `REACH_ID` = 440030100008 and a `CO_FIPS` = 44023, it would recalculate as 440230100008. Now what I want to do is simply replace the `'!REACH_ID[-5:]'` with an incrementor. So if 440030100008 was the first `REACH_ID` in my attribute table, I want to make replace `00008` with `00001` and then for the next row, I want to add `00002`, and so on. The first problem is that its tricky creating a string incrementor, but I have overcome that issue. I can use something like this (using a 'counter'):

```
x = '00000'
for i in range(0, 10):
    x = str(int(x) + 1).zfill(len(x))
    print(x)
```

or as a function where length would be the row count of the feature, `layer_output` :

```
x = '00000'
f_length = arcpy.GetCount_management(layer_output)
def incrementor(counter, length):
    for i in range(0, length):
        counter = str(int(counter) + 1).zfill(len(counter))
        print(counter)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(layer_output,'REACH_ID','!CO_FIPS! + "01" + incrementor(x, f_length),'PYTHON')
```

But, the problem is...how does one get the incrementor to work inside of the expression in CalculateField_management? Am I going about this the wrong way? I haven't come across any other questions that explain how to achieve this.

Comment: See this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154