# Count duplicates in a field for sequential unique ID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, unique-id

I am trying to create a unique ID for my street feature class. (My unique ID starts with first 3 letters of the Street Name, 2 letters of the Street type, and 3 letters of the City Name Abbreviated.)

Where I am stuck is that I am trying to get a number to increment on the segments that would be duplicated.  For example, Glenacre Drive has three segments. The UniqueID would be `GLEDRHQF01`, `GLEDRHQF02`, `GELDRHQF03`.

I cannot figure out how to create sequential numbers not based off of the ObjectID sorting... For example, I used the following Field Calculator but realized it is looking at the ObjectID sort and my streets aren't entered in order...

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
prevFieldValue = ''
counter = 1
def GetDuplicateCounter(myFieldValue):
  global prevFieldValue
  global counter
  if myFieldValue == prevFieldValue:
    counter += 1
  else:
    counter = 1
  prevFieldValue = myFieldValue
  return counter

=
GetDuplicateCounter( !UNIQUEID! )
```

Comment: You can't control the order of the objectids, and only by specifying an ORDER BY can you run an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` calculation.

Comment: See if this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154 helps

Comment: As an aside, unique IDs should generally be simple unique integers.  In general, including anything with actual meaning (eg, abbreviated streets), has the potential to cause problems later on (eg, street might have a name change).  Anything with actual meaning should be in normal attribute fields, rather than unique identifiers.  (Using simple integers also has the advantage of faster database indexing for searching/joining, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried [Sort](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm)? Or just sort the table manually in the attriburte table by right-clicking one of the gray headers then **Advanced sorting**