# Calculate Field in ArcGIS Pro with autoIncrement based on another attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, autoincrement

I want to use Calculate Field in ArcGIS Pro to count up sequentially, but start over with each new group. The groups are defined by FEATUREID.

Example of desired output:

FEATUREID       GEOMETRYID
A               1
A               2
A               3
B               1
C               1
C               2

How can I modify the AutoIncrement() script to produce my desired result?

```
    rec=0
def SequentialNumber():
    global rec
    pStart = 1
    pInterval = 1
    if (rec == 0):
        rec = pStart
    else:
        rec = rec + pInterval
    return rec
```

Comment: Or this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class#200154

Comment: I hadn't seen the info from the first comment before, but couldn't get that to work. 
I had already seen the page FelixIP linked earlier today. Not sure what error I made then, but upon review I did get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the expression box:

//FIELD is the name of the field that you want to use as a unique identifier/what you want to group by

```
    GroupOrder(!FIELD!)
```

And in the code box:

```
d={}
def GroupOrder(FIELD):
  N=d.get(FIELD,0);N+=1
  d[FIELD]=N
  return N
```

This is the copy of the python command:

```
    arcpy.management.CalculateField("dataset_name", "Field_calc", GroupOrder( !FIELD!)", "PYTHON3", """d={}
    def GroupOrder(FIELD):
      N=d.get(FIELD,0);N+=1
      d[FIELD]=N
      return N""", "TEXT", "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS")
//replace dataset_name with the name of your layer
//replace Field_calc with the name of the field you're trying to calculate information for
//replace the 4 instances of FIELD with the name of the field you're grouping by
```

This will produce:

[image: table of prodecut]

Comment: Ok overall, but too many changes to my code, GroupOrder(!FIELD!) would suffice without any modification of code within function itself. +1 for efforts.