# Find duplicates and merge attributes arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, merge, cursor, dictionary

I have a point shapefile which has duplicate points based on an "ID".

ID1 + permit1 + resources associated to permit

ID1 + permit2 + resources associated to permit

ID2 + permit1 + resources associated to permit

etc.

In my output I want 1 point for each ID but want to merge all associated permit and resources information for that one point into one row.

I have found some helpful scripts online (credit specifically to Xander Bakker: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/arcpy-search-duplicate-attributes-then-update/td-p/534281) on how to use search cursors, dictionaries, and update cursors to merge attributes into just one field (permits). However, I am struggling to adjust my script to also update additional fields (resources).

Additionally, I think I need to create new fields with a greater character limit and populate those fields instead of the existing fields so I don't run into an issue with limited character spaces in the existing fields.

See photos below for desired output.

How do I manipulate and/or simplify my code to update not just one field but both fields (permit and resources)?

Dictionaries are confusing!

[image: input example]

[image: output example]

Current script (which is only updating the existing permit field):

```
def main():
    fc_in = intersect_output
    fc_out = r"D:\DRC\vector\intersect_output_clean.shp"
    fld_id = "ID"
    fld_permit = "Permit"
    sr = arcpy.Describe(fc_in).spatialReference
    
    # create empty output fc
    fc_ws, fc_name = os.path.split(fc_out)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(fc_ws, fc_name, template=fc_in, spatial_reference=sr)

    # create dictionary with ID's to store related permits 
    flds = (fld_id, fld_permit)
    dct = {}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_in, flds) as curs_in:
        for row_in in curs_in:
            p_id = row_in[0]
            p_permit = row_in[1]
            if p_id in dct:
                dct[p_id] += "+ {0}".format(p_permit)
            else:
                dct[p_id] = p_permit

    del row_in, curs_in

    # now do the update:
    flds = correctFieldList(arcpy.ListFields(fc_out))
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc_out, flds) as curs_out:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_in, flds) as curs_in:
            for row_in in curs_in:
                lst_row = list(row_in)
                p_id = row_in[flds.index(fld_id)]
                if p_id in dct:
                    permits = dct[p_id]
                    lst_row[flds.index(fld_permit)] = permits 
                    tmp = dct.pop(p_id)
                    curs_out.insertRow(tuple(lst_row))

def correctFieldList(flds):
    flds_use = ['Shape@']
    fldtypes_not = ['Geometry', 'Guid', 'OID']
    for fld in flds:
        if not fld.type in fldtypes_not:
            flds_use.append(fld.name)
    return flds_use

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I've got to frame challenge here. The "multiple rows in one row" model is a violation of basic relational principles. It's far better to model this with a one-to-many join, at which point you'll be using the software as designed and tested. Attempting this with shapefile, with all its limitations, can only make an ugly solution tragic.

Comment: Vince, are you politely suggesting that I work with feature classes within a geodatabase instead of shapefiles? Additionally, running a one-to-many spatial join would give me duplicate points in my output which is not the end goal. I have tried a one-to-one spatial join and instructed the tool to join attributes for the two fields I want to aggregate attributes for. However, some of the rows in the output included the join delimiter that I set (a + sign) but nothing after the plus sign... which I assume means it did not successfully join the attributes from both tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Concatenate 2 fields into new field COMBO and use this field calculator [expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154) to compute consecutive number per ID:

[image]

Use Pivot table tool to get this:

[image]

Delete identical in a copy of original shapefile and join pivot table to it.