# ArcGIS Pro - Summarize within - 90th percentile

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, summarizing

I have some point data which has a response time in minutes value. I've generated a hexagon tessellation and I want to calculate the 90th percentile response time for values falling within each of the tessellation hexes.

I can use summarize within to give me the mean of the point data however would like to report on the 90th percentile.

- Is there a way in ArcGIS Pro to do this either with a tool or with
  Python code?

I'm aware Zonal Statistics can calculate 90th percentiles but because there are multiple points falling within the cell, when I convert to raster (Point to Raster), the cell assignment type selection will 'remove' the key information.

[image: Point data in blue]

Comment: Intersect points and polygons and sort output points by resp.time. Calculate their seq.numbers per polygon https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154  Indiv.rows with min( abs(seqNo/totalPerPolygon)-0.9) is the one you need.