# Renaming Attachments based on field value in related table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attachments

I have an inspections database which includes a feature class with attached photos from the inspections for each feature.  The inspectors have not been renaming the photos when they take them to identify what feature each one goes to because they felt it unnecessary given that it was already related specifically to that feature.

That is all good and well until I have to extract them to a folder for long-term storage and reference outside of any software interacting with our GIS.  When I batch export them, I can name them based on the fields in the _ATTACH table they are stored in, but that doesn't include any field that matches how we identify the features being inspected.  It has the relationship guid, but that's impractical as a naming scheme because someone looking in our photos folder for a specific feature's photo would have to cross reference the relationship guid of the feature with the name of the photo.

What I would like to be able to do is change the names of the photos stored in the _ATTACH table to a name based on the value of a field in the feature class for the feature they are related to.  I only have limited Python scripting experience, though, and I would like to have a solution in less time than it would take for me to learn to develop a script on my own to grab the feature name field and move it over the being part of the name of each attached photo.

Is there a better way to do this without scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with very little coding, because it is possible to rename attachments inside attachment table. Picture shows feature class (FC) and attachment table. In this case they are related via FC objectID. In you case it might be GlobalID.
[image]

Use join field tool to transfer feature name to attachments table, to get something like this. Note last field that I added and populated using expression from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154).

[image]

Recalculate ATT_NAME field. I used:

```
"%s_%s.jpg" %( !NAME!,str( !Group_No!).zfill(2))
```

to get this:

[image]

These are the names you'll get when extracting pictures from database.